# TypeError: Model is not a Constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Making a MongoDB call from a react component on Form Submit with Mongoose throws an error - TypeError: Group is not a constructor at below line

```
let group1 = new Group
```

I have a server file inside which I initialize the connection.

**server.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('dbName',{ useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connection.once('open',() =>{
    console.log('connected to the database');
});
```

Then there is a model file called **group.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var groupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    groupName: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Group',groupSchema);
```

**Component CreateNew**

```
const Group = require('../models/group');

class CreateNew extends Component {
// code here
render()
// code here

<Form onSubmit = {e => {

    let group1 = new Group({
    groupName: 'My Group'
    });
    group1.save(function(err,group1){
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('mongo success');
    });

}}>
```

When I put all the code in one place like [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) inside the server.js file then the code works and I can see the data in Mongo.

If I just shift the code from inside Form's onSubmit to before the 'class CreateNew extends Component' line just for testing then it throws following error

> Cannot overwrite `Group` model once compiled.

at this line

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Group',groupSchema);
```

Comment: You're trying to run server-side (node) JS on the client. React apps are written in JS, and they also use modules, but they still run in the browser and as such don't have direct access to DB / mongodb commands. You need to split your project into two separate ones: a backend (node+mongodb+express) and a frontend (React). In the backend project, use express to create an API with routes like `/create/group`, in the frontend use `fetch()` to make requests to the API.

Comment: @user3884753 Why undrementioned answer isn't correct for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll show you a short overview of the project, which includes frontend and backend.

1. BACKEND

   1.1 server.js

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const app = express();
   const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
   const http = require('http').Server(app);
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
   const routes = require(path_to_api.js)(router);

   app.use('/myApi', routes)
   //***Here you should implement more details about your project such as routes, body parsers and other middlewares*****//

   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/your-app-name', err => err?console.log(err):console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB'));

   http.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`Server running on ${port}`))
   ```

   1.2 Model, group.js

   ```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
   const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   let groupSchema = new Schema({
      groupName: {
         type: String
      }
   });

   module.exports = mongoose.model('Group',groupSchema);
   ```

   1.3 api.js (Still backend!!!)

   ```
   const Group = require(path_to_group.js);

   module.exports = router => {
     router.post('/group', (req, res)=> {
        let group = new Group();
        group.groupName = req.body.groupName;

        //Save in database
        group.save(function(err){
         ...
        })
     }
     return router
   }
   ```
2. FRONTEND

   2.1 Ajax calls (service.js)

   ```
   function group(data){
      return fetch('/api/authenticate',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
     }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
           return data //Server response
     })
   }
   export {group}
   ```

   2.2 React Component

   ```
   import {group} from //service.js path

   class CreateNew extends Component {
    constructor(props, context){
      this.sendGroupName = this.sendGroupName.bind(this);
    }

    this.sendGroupName(){
      let data = //data received from form after submit

      //It is the most important part from the frontend - sending data to the server
      group(data).then(res => {
         //do somenthing with servers response
      }
    }         

    render(){
      <Form onSubmit={this.sendGroupName}>
        //Form content such as inputs, labels...
      <Form/>
    }
   ```

That is my quickly explanation concerning MEAN projects. I hpe it will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I used your framework with some slight modification related to my project and it worked.